# Reacting Event on Filter in MudDataGrid

Tags: datagrid, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a `MudDataGrid` where I support filtering on my source column and I want to execute code, whenever the filtering is updated.
I have looked at the API and intellisense and I cannot see any events related to filtering, that I can listen to.

Currently I am able to manually trigger my code after the filtering has occured, but I would like it to be automated.

I declare my Data grid as follows:

```
<MudDataGrid @ref="DataGrid" Items="Statistics.OrderByDescending(x => x.DeliveryDate)">
                <Columns>
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Source" Title="Source" Filterable="true" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.DeliveryDate" Title="Deliverydate" Filterable="true" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Price" Title="Price" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Attempts" Title="Attempts required" />
                    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Inserted" Title="Inserted UTC" />
                </Columns>
 </MudDataGrid>
```

In my Code-Behind file I have a property declared:
`MudDataGrid<Statistic> DataGrid { get; set; } = default!;`

Then in my function I use the `FilteredItems` property

`var visibleItems = DataGrid.FilteredItems.GroupBy(x => x.Source);`

I am looking for any event I can listen for, so that I can run my code automatically, after the filtering is updated

I tried reviewing the API documentation https://mudblazor.com/api/datagrid#pages but I could not find any events related to filtering.

I have also not been able to find any posts online with a similar issue

I have added an example here:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkcRvQPxmXIZNpGL

When you click the button, you see the filtered values.
How can I hook up an event, to set the text upon filtering?

Comment: how are you updating the filters? Can you create a snippet of your code here https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/

Comment: Example added.
When you click the button, you see the filtered items. How can I hook that up to an event, so I can avoid the button?